# Difference between a ProtectionDomain and an AccessControlContext

Tags: java, access-control, jaas

Could someone explain what the difference is between a `ProtectionDomain` and an `AccessControlContext`?

I am reading `JAAS in Action` and from what I can see these two classes seem to be very similar. I can not get what is the difference as they both define current security context, i.e. who runs code and what privileges it has.